# App designed for iPhone only crashing on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, size-classes

I am having an issue with my new app which is already on the App Store. Problem is that when I created it I selected just to be for iPhone, some users are reporting that it is also available for iPad and for iPad 2 the app is crashing..

I used Auto-Layout and Size Classes features, but did all work on Compact Width, Any Height, so all iPhones.

Also on "Build Settings" the flag "Targeted Device Family" is set to "1", which is iPhone/iPod.

Update: after receiving an email from user reporting that the app loads fine but when he inputs data on the UITextField, then it crashes.

So checking my button action and running the code on a real iPad for testing I am getting a nil object but don't know where from.

Here's the code:

```
 @IBAction func btnHourRate(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    if self.hourRate > 0 {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Hourly Rate", message: "Your current rate is: $\(strRate)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    } else {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Hourly Rate", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    }

    //Configure UITextField
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "0.00"
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
        self.tField = textField
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

        //Saving Rate to NSUserDefaults
        self.defaults.setObject(self.tField.text, forKey: "Rate")
        self.defaults.synchronize()

    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: And do you have any crash logs? Have you been able to reproduce the issue yourself?

Comment: No crash logs and no errors using iPad Simulators. So I can't reproduce the error, the code runs just fine on iPad Simulator, but of course the UI is not good because it wasn't designed for the iPad.

Comment: see yourself in itunes. it is there that your app is compatible with iphone and IPAD. whether you design it or not for iPad, when you download the app on iPad, the app will appear just like in iphone with retina 2x and without retina 1x. So you can't just design for iphone. even if you design it for iphone only, it is compatible to ipad also

Comment: Your app it's not universal. When users download your app on iPad, they will see the 3.5" iPhone version. So the error must be related to iOS version, small screen size or something else. Post the error logs, must help.

Comment: Have a look at your iTC record for the crash logs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ImprovingCustomersExperience.html

Comment: When I go to crash reports I get: "Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown." The strange thing is that the app works fine with no errors or crashes on all iPad Simulator.

Comment: Got an email form a user saying that the app loads fine, images all there, but he tries to input data nothing happens and after some attempts then it crashes.

Comment: Found the error in code and fixed. How should I post answer? Here, commenting or as a formal answer?